# LoadControlState not getting fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I'm having problems with a custom control (which inherits from a user control) - my LoadControlState isn't getting fired.

Well, to be precise: it gets fired normally, but when i override the page's LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium and SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium functions, it no longer gets fired.

Are there any typical reasons for the LoadControlState not getting fired that i should look into? Are there any preconditions for when it *does* get fired?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed it:

```
    PageStatePersister pageStatePersister;
    protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
    {
        get
        {
            // Unlike as exemplified in the MSDN docs, we cannot simply return a new PageStatePersister
            // every call to this property, as it causes problems
            return pageStatePersister ?? (pageStatePersister = new SessionPageStatePersister(this));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's how i'm overriding the Save/LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium functions. Basically, it stores the viewstate in the users session, to make the postbacks faster:

```
    // Inspired by: http://aspalliance.com/72
    const string ViewStateFieldName = "__VIEWSTATEKEY";
    const string ViewStateKeyPrefix = "ViewState_";
    const string RecentViewStateQueue = "ViewStateQueue";
    const int RecentViewStateQueueMaxLength = 5;

    protected override object LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    {
        // The cache key for this viewstate is stored in a hidden field, so grab it
        string viewStateKey = Request.Form[ViewStateFieldName] as string;
        if (viewStateKey == null) return null;

        // Grab the viewstate data using the key to look it up
        return Session[viewStateKey];
    }

    protected override void SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium(object viewState)
    {
        // Give this viewstate a random key
        string viewStateKey = ViewStateKeyPrefix + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Store the viewstate
        Session[viewStateKey] = viewState;

        // Store the viewstate's key in a hidden field, so on postback we can grab it from the cache
        ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField(ViewStateFieldName, viewStateKey);

        // Some tidying up: keep track of the X most recent viewstates for this user, and remove old ones
        var recent = Session[RecentViewStateQueue] as Queue<string>;
        if (recent == null) Session[RecentViewStateQueue] = recent = new Queue<string>();
        recent.Enqueue(viewStateKey); // Add this new one so it'll get removed later
        while (recent.Count > RecentViewStateQueueMaxLength) // If we've got lots in the queue, remove the old ones
            Session.Remove(recent.Dequeue());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 2.0, it is recommended to put your state persistent logic in a custom class derived from [PageStatePersister](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pagestatepersister.aspx). So you may try taking that approach.

Comment: I've also tried that, by overriding the Page's PageStatePersister property and returning 'new SessionPageStatePersister(this);' - this has the same outcome as before.

Comment: @Chris, are you calling Page.RegisterRequiresControlState in OnInit of your custom control? Yet another thing to check if control id is getting changed (or assigned later).

Answer (score 0):

What are you returning from your `LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium` method implementation? It should probably be an instance of the [System.Web.UI.Pair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx) initialized with both the ViewState and the ControlState data:

```
return new Pair([Restored ControlState], [Restored ViewState]);
```

Comment: In my SavePageStateToPersistenceMedium, i'm simply saving the passed 'viewState' object, which is a Pair (i tested with breakpoints). And upon loading, i just reload that pair. So i assume that pair is already the control and viewstate?

Comment: Where do i get the controlstate from when saving? Page.ControlState doesn't exist.

Comment: @Chris: base.PageStatePersister.ControlState